# Как получить содержимое элемента с помощью this

Tags: javascript, html

Предположим у меня есть группа элементов с одинаковыми классами, как получить содержимое элемента при клике по нему, я так понимаю эту задачу можно решить с помощью this, но я не знаю как, дело в том что заранее не известно количество элементов с одинаковыми классами а значить устанавливать для каждого элемента уникальное id не возможно. Заранее спасибо

Вот пример разметки

```html
<div class="form_switch">
    Пункт 1
</div>

<div class="form_switch">
    Пункт 2
</div>

<div class="form_switch">
    Пункт 3
</div>

<div class="form_switch">
    Пункт 4
</div>

<div class="form_switch">
    Пункт 5
</div>

<div class="form_switch">
    Пункт 6
</div>

<div class="form_swich">
    Пункт 7
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По поводу `this` в обработчиках событий можно почитать тут: [Введение в браузерные события](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events).

Но чтобы не навешивать обработчики на все элементы, лучше использовать [делегирование событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation) и для этого поместить элементы в контейнер (если они ещё не в подходящем для этого элементе).

```js
document.querySelector('#switches').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  const target = event.target;

  if (target.className !== 'form_switch') return;

  console.log(target.innerText);
});
```

```html
<div id="switches">

  <div class="form_switch">
    Пункт 1
  </div>

  <div class="form_switch">
    Пункт 2
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Без добавления id-шников

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.form_switch').forEach(form_switch => {
    form_switch.addEventListener('click', e => {
        console.log(form_switch.innerHTML);
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="form_switch">
    Пункт 1
</div>

<div class="form_switch">
    Пункт 2
</div>

<div class="form_switch">
    Пункт 3
</div>

<div class="form_switch">
    Пункт 4
</div>

<div class="form_switch">
    Пункт 5
</div>

<div class="form_switch">
    Пункт 6
</div>

<div class="form_swich">
    Пункт 7
</div>
```